# Video camera interface between beaglebone and android

Tags: android, beagleboard

I am trying to develop an application in which a Beaglebone platform captures video images from a camera connected to it, and then send them (through an internet socket) to an Android application such the application shows the video images.

I have read that openCV may be a very good option to capture the images from a camera, but then I am not sure how the images can be sent through a socket.

On the other end, I think that the video images received by the Android application could be treated by simple images. With this in mind I think I can refresh the image every second or so.

I am not sure if I am in the right way for the implementation, so I really appreciate any suggestion and help you could provide.

Thanks in advance, Gus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folks at OpenROV have done something like you've said. Instead of using a custom Android app, which is certainly possible, they've simply used a web browser to display the images captured.

https://github.com/OpenROV/openrov-software

This application uses OpenCV to perform the capture and analysis, a Node.JS application to transmit the data over socket.io to the web browser and a web client to display the video. An architecture description on how this works is given here:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uvnAYDxbDUo

You can also look at running something like mjpg-streamer:

http://digitalcommons.calpoly.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1051&context=cpesp

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information. From what I checked, they are using a java app for data transmission, how could I do that via a C program (transmitting the info via socket)? And any idea about programming the client side?  Also, do you know if it possible to do the same using Angstrom distro?. I am asking you since I could not find any link to contact them.

Comment: It is actually a JavaScript application, which is a different language than Java. They use OpenCV for the video capture itself.

Comment: It is certainly possible to do the same thing under Angstrom (which ships with the OpenCV libraries installed--you can see my [BeagleStache demo](http://beagleboard.org/project/stache). It is also possible to do the whole thing in just C, but you'll need to be familiar with socket programming. An example of [streaming to Android using RTP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11452865/displaying-live-udp-or-rtp-stream-multicast-on-android) might be useful to you.

Comment: I've added another link to show you another architecture if you don't want to use JavaScript code. I just think the Node.JS approach is the most elegant as it doesn't require any special client-side app--just a browser.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the info, this is very helpful. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Jadon, from all the information you provided I have a new question. The code you use to "define" the "object" for the camera is "capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(numCamera);". Once I connect the camera to the Beaglebone through the USB port, how can I know the parameter "numCamera"? If I use this definition "capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( CV_CAP_ANY );", will the camera be recognized automatically? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I use -1 to select the default camera in my [mustache app](https://github.com/jadonk/stache/blob/master/stache.cpp#L99).

Comment: Jadon, I have not been able to make it work (using the same camera you used). I followed similar code from your BeagleStache project, but it seems that after doing "capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(-1);" (or with 0), the camera is not recognize since the code does not go into the "if" statement ("if(capture)"). How can I solve this? Should I update the version I have of openCV? If so, how can I do that?

Comment: I'd guess it is an issue with the kernel driver for your camera, but I really don't have a lot to go on here. Perhaps you can try the PS3 Eye?

Comment: I finally found out that the distro I am using in Beaglebone is not the appropriate to work with the camera and opencv. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

Note that displaying the video stream as a set of images can have big performance impact. For example, if you are not careful how you encode each frame, you can more than double the traffic between the two systems. ARGB takes 32 bits to encode a pixel, YUV takes 12 bits, so even accounting for the frame compression, you still are doubling the storage per frame. Also, rendering ARGB is much, much slower than rendering YUV, as most of the Android phones actually have hardware-optimized YUV rendering (as in the GPU can directly blit the YUV in the display memory). In addition, rendering separate frames as approach usually make sone take the easy way and render a Bitmap on a Canvas, which works if you are content with something in the order of 10-15 fps, but can never get to 60 fps, and can get to a peak (not sustained) of 30 fps only on very few phones.

If you have a hardware MPEG encoder on the Beaglebone board, you should use it to encode and stream the video. This would allow you to directly pass the MPEG stream to the standard Android media player for rendering. Of course, using the standard media player will not allow you to process the video stream in real time, so depending on your scenario this might not be an option for you.